# Address behaviour with dynamic memory allocation in C

Tags: c, pointers, variables, dynamic

I wrote the following two codes and their outputs are given respectively.

Code 1:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int* allocate(int array, int value)
{
    int k[array];
    //int *k=(int *)malloc(array*sizeof(int));
    for(int i=0;i<array;i++)
    {
        k[i]=value;
        printf("%d ",k[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return k;
}
int main(void)
{
    int *p=allocate(3,25);
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        printf("%d ",p);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
25 25 25
0 0 0
```

Code 2:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int* allocate(int array, int value)
{
    //int k[array];
    int *k=(int *)malloc(array*sizeof(int));
    for(int i=0;i<array;i++)
    {
        k[i]=value;
        printf("%d ",k[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return k;
}
int main(void)
{
    int *p=allocate(3,25);
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        printf("%d ",p);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
25 25 25
12329552 12329552 12329552
```

I understand that in the first code, the data is allocated in the stack, and it would be cleared by the compiler once the return statement is executed.  But I'm just printing 'p' and not '*p'.  Why it shows 0?  After all, pointer *p is declared within the main().

Kindly explain in simple terms.  Thanks in advance.

EDIT 1:  I'm adding a new code to make my question clear.
Code 3:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int* allocateArray(int size, int value)
{
int arr[size];
for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
arr[i] = value;
}
return arr;
}

int main(void)
{
    int* vector = allocateArray(5,45);
for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
printf("%d\t", &vector[i]);
}
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0 4 8 12 16
```

In the third code, I can't print vector[i] or *(vector+i).  The compiler terminates the program.

The explanation of 0 and the pattern in the output of the third code is what all I need.

Comment: I suspect a compiler optimization has realized that the return value is invalid, so it's just returning a null pointer.

Comment: BTW, you should use `%p` to print pointers, not `%d`.

Comment: This is implementation-dependent. When I run it on my Mac, I get the actual address. But I also get a compiler warning: **warning: address of stack memory associated with local variable 'k' returned [-Wreturn-stack-address]**

Comment: @Barmar I tried with %p.  The results are same.  I'll edit the question to make it more clear.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I know it doesn't change the results, it was just a general recommendation.

Comment: You're invoking undefined behavior, the results can be anything. Why do you care?

Comment: @Barmar See the third code.  The output pattern doesn't seem like an undefined behaviour to me.  Correct me if I'm wrong.  I'm just a beginner learning C pointers.

Comment: @Subash - Undefined behavior means that *anything* can happen. Absolutely anything. Displaying zero included.

Comment: @BoPersson If it's undefined, then why a pattern follows in the output of the third code?

Comment: `&vector[i]` is the same as `vector + i`. Since `vector` is `0`, that's why you get those results.

Comment: @Subash - Displaying what seems like a pattern (or not) is also included in *anything* can happen. No rules apply.

Comment: *the data is allocated in the stack, and it would be cleared by the compiler once the return statement is executed.* No, the variable referred to by the pointer **ceases to exist**.  It's not "cleared".  The result can be anything.  There is no "why", there is no "what".  It's just **wrong** to refer to it anymore.

Comment: @Barmar Since the vector is 0, I should get 0 1 2 3 4 as my output, if I print &vector[i] or (vector+i).  I tried it in my compiler, by simply printing i.  But the output is 0 4 8 12 16.

Comment: You need to read up on pointer arithmetic. It automatically multiplies by the size of the type it points to, and `sizeof(int)` is 4.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Makes sense.  So you say that, it's useless to care about the address of the pointer, in which the pointed or referred variable had caesed to exist.  It's right?

Comment: @subash *undefined behaviour* refers to the c language standard. The standard defines that if you do certain things, then it is not defined what happens by the standard. That means that in those situations, compiler 1 on system A could yield nothing, and the other compiler on system B could  format your harddrive when you run the same program. The fact that your program outputs all zeros when accessing a variable that ceased ro exist is unreliable, other compilers, or another version of your compiler or during new moon the program might travel back in time (if your Hardware supports that)...

Comment: @MichaelBeer I love the way you did put the explanation.  Thanks, man.  I got it now.

Comment: @Subash: Just out of curiosity: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: @alk I'm using CodeBlocks 17.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your answer you explain that you understand that you are returning a pointer to an array in `allocate` that *ceases to exist* before the pointer is assigned to `p` in `main`, and are wondering why a null pointer appears to be returned instead of a 'realistic' stack pointer, for instance.

#### Why is `NULL` allowed?

As explained in the comments, your compiler also knows that the pointer will not be valid by the time it is examined, and so can return a null pointer because of the following rule:

> *From ISO/IEC 9899:2011 Section 6.2.4*:
>   The value of a pointer **becomes indeterminate** when the object it points to (or just past) reaches the end of its lifetime.

By indeterminate, it means the value of such a pointer will be *unspecified* or potentially a *trap representation* (which causes undefined behavior if read by any operation), which means a null pointer would be fine to return, as well as a pointer to another existing object, a pointer to no object, and a pointer value that could cause crashes or unexpected behavior in your program.

#### Why did the compiler pick `NULL`?

As for *why* the compiler implementation decided on a null pointer, possibly because it's a choice which is unlikely to silently break your program. A compiler will not usually impact performance to save you from yourself, but here it is at full liberty to optimize much of the preceding function away and simply return a null pointer that in a typical hosted environment will cause an immediate segfault if it is dereferenced, rather than allowing for the possibility of overwriting other objects in memory by trying to use the 'allocated' array.